# How to embed a React web app using react-router

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, typescript, react-router, webforms

I am developing a React Web App, that will have to be embedded in an ASP.NET Web Forms website. I managed to embed it in an aspx page, by loading the js scripts of the web app, but I am currently having problems with react-router.
Now I am trying on my local machine, the website is served by http://localhost/website path.
The web app will be in http://localhost/website/webapp (or http://localhost/website/webapp.aspx).
Is there a specific basename to set to react-router or is there a way to set it dinamically?
Thanks

I tried to change the basename to "/webapp" but it didn't work.

Comment: I managed to make it work. In <BrowserRouter> component I set "/website/webapp". the problem is the same app has to be served in a mobile page with the following path "http://localhost/website/mobile/webapp". Is there a way to make it dynamic? Thanks